# QGIS 3.26.2 Misplaced attribute window

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, features

I don't know if this is the right place to set my problem. Almost every time I right click to end the creation of a vector entity, the window of the feature attribute is out of my screen. It's just annoying. Is there any button to reset it to a default place?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the window appears, move it to the place you want, fill in the values (or leave it empty) and click `OK` (or hit `ENTER`).

Next time the dialog window will appear in the place you put it before.

If the problem persits, try restarting QGIS with a new, fresh profile: `Menu Settings > User Profiles > New Profile...`

Comment: I think it has to do something with the zoom. If I do what you wrote, yes it stays in the same place, but if I zoom in, draw a line for example, and right click, it will go out of the screen.  So if I keep the scale stable, the window also stays at place. But if I zoom in or out, It will go to the borders of the screen.

Comment: See updated answer: try opening QGIS with a new profile

Comment: Yes it popped up in the middle of the screen every time! Thank you!